# PrimeReact DataTable: How to modify the value of one cell based on another

Tags: reactjs, datatable, grid, primereact

I am testing the DataTable component of PrimeReact. Just testing because I can't yet decide which component library to use.

I'm using editMode="cell" and the onCellEditComplete callback of DataTable when modifying a field and with the rowData prop I modify another field (another cell). It seems to modify it but when editing that cell the input text doesn't update properly.

Example:

```
   const onCellEditComplete = (e) => {
         let { rowData, newValue, value, field } = e;
        
         if (field=="code") { //code is the modified field/cell

            rowData["code2"]="pref"+rowData["code"]; //an expression
            //'code2' is the other field to update based en 'code'
        }
        // ...
     }
```

When trying to edit the cell of 'code2' field, the input doesn't update. It shows the previous value.

Answer (score 0):

Your rowData should look like this: rowData.code2="pref"+rowData.code